# JQ: Delete key:value pairs anywhere in JSON tree

Tags: json, jq

I am looking for a way to delete key:value pairs (where key is a known string) anywhere in the JSON tree with `jq`.

Specifically: I would like to delete `"type": "Link"` and `"linkType": "Entry"` everywhere (in all parts of the hierarchy, where ever they appear). My JSON file is +800000 rows long and is nested deeply.

Snippet:

```
{
  "entries": [
    {
      "sys": {
        "id": "vcLKKhJ3mZNfGMvVZZi07",
        "contentType": {
          "sys": {
            "id": "page"
          }
        }
      },
      "fields": {
        "title": {
          "de-DE": "Startseite",
          "en-US": "Home"
        },
        "description": {
          "en-US": "foo"
        },
        "keywords": {
          "en-US": "bar"
        },
        "stageModules": {
          "en-US": [
            {
              "sys": {
                "type": "Link",
                "linkType": "Entry",
                "id": "11AfBBuNK8bx3EygAS3WTY"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried so many different things to iterate through the file to remove these two from the output, I constantly end up with "Cannot index array with string". E.g.

```
[ .[] | select(.linkType != "Entry", .type != "Link" ) ]
```

Ideal result:

```
{
  "entries": [
    {
      "sys": {
        "id": "vcLKKhJ3mZNfGMvVZZi07",
        "contentType": {
          "sys": {
            "id": "page"
          }
        }
      },
      "fields": {
        "title": {
          "de-DE": "Startseite",
          "en-US": "Home"
        },
        "description": {
          "en-US": "foo"
        },
        "keywords": {
          "en-US": "bar"
        },
        "stageModules": {
          "en-US": [
            {
              "sys": {
                "id": "11AfBBuNK8bx3EygAS3WTY"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Can someone help me out?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you always want to remove the `type` and `linkType` key, or only if the value matches something?

Comment: I want to remove the whole key, including the value. They are all the same, so matching is less important for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `jq` manual:

> The walk(f) function applies f recursively to every component of the
> input entity.

Use this to recursively go through all items, check your conditions and use `del` if necessary:

```
walk(
  if type == "object" and .type == "Link" then del(.type) else . end
)
```

Edit: If "matching is less important", as you state, then just use `del` on any object:

```
walk(if type == "object" then del(.type, .linkType) else . end)
```

Comment: Alternatively, use `..` to reach all items in the tree, select objects and delete as before: `(.. | select(type == "object")) |= del(.type, .linkType)`